# WooCommerce main shop page shows no products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this strange problem that occur every once in a while. (Helpful, I know, but let me explain).

I'm building a WooCommerce site and every once in a while, I'm noticing that the main shop page (the product archive page as it were) doesn't show any of the products - but once I click one of the categories, it correctly shows all products connected to that category.

The weird part is that it seems to happens randomly. To try and find the problem in my code, I remove part after part until it starts working. And then when I add back my code, it continues to work and I have no problem whatsoever - making this a very strange bug that's super hard to diagnoze, let alone fix.

At least I managed to echo the actual SQL query. So here is the SQL query that it uses when it shows no products:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (wp_posts.ID = '18') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

The page with the ID 18 is the actual page that is set as shop page:

[image]

Just for reference, this is what the SQL query should look like:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (15) ) ) AND ((wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private'))) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC, wp_posts.post_title ASC LIMIT 0, 16
```

So, what's going on here? Why doesn't the loop reset to show the actual products?

Answer (score 0):

**Please Remove any custom query from archive page and put this code in function.php file.**

```
function fwp_archive_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( is_tax( 'product_cat' ) || is_post_type_archive('product') ) {
        
        $query->set( 'showposts', 16 );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 16 );
        

    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'fwp_archive_per_page' );
```

Comment: No, I don't run any custom query at all. And that line didn't do anything at all either.